# STM32 SPI transfer only working correctly with first transfer, is there a relationship between the correct numbers and received values?

Tags: stm32, spi

I have a custom PCB that contains a stm32f411re and a stm32f446re with the f411 acting as SPI master and the f446 is the slave. At the moment I have some very simple code, with the slave waiting in a loop until a SPI transfer is initiated by the master. The slave then transfer the following values:

```
uint16_t scope_test_data[46] = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,7,47,98,146,193,237,280,321,361,398,434,469,502,534,564,593,621,648,673,698,721,744,765,786,806,825,843,860,877,893,908,923,937,951,963,976,988,999,1};
```

using `HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi3, scope_test_data, sizeof(scope_test_data), HAL_MAX_DELAY);`

The master receives these values correctly on the first transfer. I then reset the slave (the master has control of the RST pin) and request the transfer again. Every transfer after this initially succesful transfer is wrong. Interestingly, the values sent are always exactly the same so I wonder if this is some sort of buffer issue? I think there is a correlation between the numbers being sent and the numbers being received but I can't figure out what it is.
Here is the master running in debug, and this is the first transfer and it is succesful.
[image]

Now, the slave is reset through hardware (RST pin held high for 100ms) and then the transfer is requested again. However these are the values I receive:
[image]

Interestingly, these are the values that are received every time after the initial transfer, so it is consistent. I think there may be some kind of bit shifting going on as the last 12 numbers are zeroI can't figure out the relationship between the two different sets of numbers. The SPI is set up as 8 bit and to get around transferring 16 bits I'm using a union:

```
    union SPI_signal_recovery_curve{
        uint16_t a[46];
        uint8_t b[92];
    };
union SPI_signal_recovery_curve spi_recovery_tx;
union SPI_signal_recovery_curve spi_recovery_rx;
```

and am using this simple  HAL function:

```
memset(spi_recovery_tx.b, 0, sizeof(spi_recovery_tx));
        
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI_Select_GPIO_Port, SPI_Select_Pin, RESET);
        HAL_Delay(1);
        while(HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi3, spi_recovery_rx.b, sizeof(spi_recovery_rx), HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK)
         sizeof(spi_recovery_rx), HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK)
        {

        }
        
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(SPI_Select_GPIO_Port, SPI_Select_Pin, SET);
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be aprpeciated. I feel like there is something simple here.

Comment: Are you sure the slave has enough time to boot and initialize itself? The master does not make sure that slave is even present, it just blindly intiates a transfer of data, and will receive garbage if there is nothing on the bus yet.

Comment: yes, the slave has enough time to boot and initialise etc. I don't bother checking becuase the slave isn;t doing anything other than waiting to send a transfer. Also, it's not random garbage that I'm receiving, it's consistent.

Comment: Problem has to be in master because slave is in same state before each transfer (if you wait long enough before transmit request). Are you sure sizeof(spi_recovery_rx) is correct I would guess it should be sizeof(spi_recovery_rx.b)?

Comment: @Rokta this is exactly my thinking. spi_recovery_rx.a and .b should be exactly the same size. Maybe I'll double check what sizeof is returning as I thought it was in bytes

Comment: spi_recovery_rx.a and spi_recovery_rx.b should be same size, but not same size as  spi_recovery_rx as you have in code.

Comment: because it's declared as a union then  spi_recovery_rx =  spi_recovery_rx .a =  spi_recovery_rx.b. They all share the same memory space. I double checked using sizeof and it returns the same value for all three. I still think my issue is a buffer overrun though.